# Displaying data from other table in php while loop

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop

I am trying to display options in select tag from another table while my
 first, while loop continues, this is what I have tried so far !!

```
<?php
     $query="SELECT * FROM `customerdata` WHERE takenby='$_SESSION[username]'";
     $query_two="SELECT * FROM `vendordriver` WHERE vendoremail='$_SESSION[username]'";
     $run_two=$db->query($query_two);
     $run=$db->query($query);
     while ($row=$run->fetch_assoc()) {
       echo " <tr><td>$row[bookingid]</td>
       <td>$row[drivername]</td>
       <td>$row[cabtype]</td>
       <td>$row[carnumber]</td><td><select>";
  while ($row_two=$run_two->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<option>$row_two[drivername]</option>";
  }
echo" </select></td>
       <td><input type='submit' class='btn btn-success' value='SEND '>
       </td>";
     }
    ?>
```

Any Suggestions Please !!!

Comment: simply create a option string first & then use it in select

Comment: Can you please,help me with the code ! I tried,but not getting satisfactory results !

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code

```
<?php
$table_1 = null;
$username = $_SESSION['username'];
$query="SELECT * FROM customerdata WHERE takenby='$username'";
$run=$db->query($query);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while ($row=$run->fetch_assoc()) {
    $table_1 = "<tr><td>$row[bookingid]</td>";
    $table_1 .= "<td>$row[drivername]</td>";
    $table_1 .= "<td>$row[cabtype]</td>";
    $table_1 .= "<td>$row[carnumber]</td><td><select>";

echo $table_1;
$query_two="SELECT * FROM vendordriver WHERE vendoremail='$username'";
$run_two=$db->query($query_two);
        while ($row_two=$run_two->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo "<option>$row_two[drivername]</option>";
        }

        echo" </select></td>
        <td><input type='submit' class='btn btn-success' value='SEND '>
        </td>";
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Define the result from the second query as an array variable then with in the first query loop with in that array to echo the drivers names here you execute second query before the first one

```
$query="SELECT * FROM `customerdata` WHERE     takenby='$_SESSION[username]'";
$query_two="SELECT * FROM `vendordriver` WHERE vendoremail='$_SESSION[username]'";
$if(!isset($array_option)){$array_option=array();}
$run_two=$db->query($query_two);
$run=$db->query($query);
while ($row_two=$run_two->fetch_assoc()) {
array_push($array_option,$row_two[driver_name];
}
```

Then within looping through first query do this

```
while ($row=$run->fetch_assoc()) {
echo " <tr><td>$row[bookingid]</td>
<td>$row[drivername]</td>
<td>$row[cabtype]</td>
<td>$row[carnumber]</td><td><select>";
for($i=0;$i<count($array_option);$i++){
echo "<option>$array_option[$i]</option>"
}
```

Then the rest of the code

```
echo" </select></td><td><input type='submit' class='btn btn-success' value='SEND '></td>";
}
?>
```